# Is there any way to swap the fn (function) and control keys in linux on a macbook pro?

Tags: linux, keyboard, macbook, macbook-pro

I don't care if this is done in the bios or a kernel module or software. Is there any way at all to do make the 'fn' key act as 'control' and the 'control' key act as 'fn' in linux running on a macbook pro?

PS. You can do this with software in OSX with the application KeyRemap4MacBook.

Comment: I think this is hardwired in the keyboard. Not sure, though.

Comment: I can't give you an exact answer, but look at how the authors of these keyboard layout files change the mappings of keys. I find that changing regular keys is rather trivial. With a bit of patience and by studying the other examples (where those files should be installed) you might be able to figure out how to remap the control and fn keys. http://colemak.com

Answer (score 1):

I personally haven't needed to do this, but this [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html) shows that you should be able to modify the kernel keymapping upon booting to make this switch.

This [link](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html#s13) also states that XFree86 will try and load the kernel mapping at its load time so it shouldn't need to be changes just for X if you do the above first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running xev from an xterm and see what the key code for fn works out to be.  bits are getting anded and orred so maybe you'll need to hold another key (ctrl) while you press fn to see data but then take the (probably 0xffe3) back out and maybe you'll have a value you can use with xmodmap.  I struggled with that d**m fn key before on those keyboards and I gave up.